# Search not giving exact result

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch

I am **searching table** but it not giving only table related records. It giving me other products also, which is irrelevant. I have set criteria in admin panel short description, price, and image. What will be issue ?

I am searching product Table but it gives me result of => **"Karoo Angel - Guardian Angel Dark Purple"** this also. Description also not contain table key anywhere. Image name also nothing related to table.

Comment: do you have add related products int catalog product add form?

Comment: no. I don`t have any related product is there.